# why is axios fetch not working on mobile?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, axios, mongodb-atlas

I have the following setup which works on my PC but doesn't on mobile even when there is data to fetch.

```
useEffect(() => {
    const {username, room} = queryString.parse(location.search);
    setRoom(room);

    if (messages.length > 3) {
        let lastMessage = messages.pop();
        setMessss([lastMessage]);
        const fetchHistory = async () => {
            try {
                const result = await axios.get(`https://example.com/messages/${room}`,);
                setMessss(result.data.messagesFromAPI);
            } catch (error) {
                console.log(error);
            }
        };
        fetchHistory();
    }
}, [messages]);
```

I also have another useEffect hook that works on PC on componentDidMount but doesn't work if I reload the page more than once but I want it to work on every page reload but it doesn't fetch...
could this be because I use the free subscription (M0) on Mongodb Atlas? Although from metrics my database hasn't exhausted or reached capacity.

```
useEffect(() => {

    const {username, room} = queryString.parse(location.search);
    // setRoom(room);

    axios.get(`https://example.com/messages/${room}`)
    .then(response => {
        const history = response.data.messagesFromAPI;
        setMessss(history);
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.log(error.response);
    });
},[]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I solved it

In the src folder just add a file called
setupProxy.js

and write this code inside

```
const { createProxyMiddleware } = require("http-proxy-middleware");
module.exports = function (app) {
  app.use(
    ["/api/*",], // the base api route you can change it
    createProxyMiddleware({
      target: "http://localhost:4000", // the local server endpoint 
    })
  );
};
```

make sure to change the target port to the port where the server is running.
For some reason axios does not behave properly locally.
You can add the setupProxy.js to .gitignore