# Network error for post request in Axios only on mobile browsers

Tags: reactjs, axios, lumen

I am using Reactjs as frontend with Lumen as backend and running them on local server. 
I am trying to call rest api from Axios using the following function.

```
import Axios from "axios";

export const apiCall = async (url, data) => {
    try {
        const response = await Axios.post(url, data);
        return response.data;
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
}
```

As the requests were getting blocked by CORS policy, I added the following code in the index.php file in Lumen project.

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, Access-Control-Allow-Origin, X-API-KEY,Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Request-Headers, Authorization, X-Auth-Token");
$headers = [
    "Access-Control-Allow-Methods" => "POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers" => "Origin, Access-Control-Allow-Origin, X-API-KEY,Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Request-Headers, Authorization, X-Auth-Token"
];

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "OPTIONS") {
    return response()->make('OK', 200, $headers);
}
```

On desktop browsers I'm getting responses successfully. But I am constantly getting Network Error on mobile browsers (both on android and ios) as following.

```
{"message":"Network Error","name":"Error","stack":"Error: Network Error at createError (http://127.0.0.1:3000/static/js/0.chunk.js:871:15)\n    at XMLHttpRequest.handleError (http://127.0.0.1:3000/static/js/0.chunk.js:366:14)","config":{"url":"http://127.0.0.1/smart_ivr/public/index.php/login/phone","method":"post","data":"{\"cli\":\"1612312312\"}","headers":{"Accept":"application/json, text/plain, */*","Content-Type":"application/json;charset=utf-8"},"transformRequest":[null],"transformResponse":[null],"timeout":0,"xsrfCookieName":"XSRF-TOKEN","xsrfHeaderName":"X-XSRF-TOKEN","maxContentLength":-1}}
```

How can I solve this issue on mobile browsers? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

this might solve it, [why is axios fetch not working on mobile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61450365/why-is-axios-fetch-not-working-on-mobile)

1 - you create a file called setupProxy.js in /src
2 - paste the code
3 - add the setupProxy.js to .gitignore

it will make a proxy for axios locally so it's kinda shortcut to make axios think the application is deployed